# Can't install Python Modules via pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to code a discord Bot with python, I was trying to download the discord module via pip and my console said this :

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install discord': The system cannot find the 
file specified.
```

I'm using a Windows 10 Pro PC and my Python Version is the newest (Python 3.9.2)

Comment: You seem to have two different folder names for Python 3.9, one with capital 'P' and another with small 'P'. I am not sure if that's the cause of the error, but it seems you have two installations and I would recommend you to keep only one of them.

Comment: Does `pip install discord.py` work?

Comment: @Deep capitalization doesn't matter on Windows.

Comment: Can you try running the command for the python launcher ``py -3.9 -m pip install discord.py``?

Comment: @MaximIvanov It worked, I also reinstalled python btw, thank you :)